# How do you show images in your posts?

Tags: support, editing

How do you show images in your posts? When I "upload the image" it doesn't show up in the question/answer.

Comment: Does text corresponding to the image file show up in the answer, or not?

Comment: Well, where is it displayed?

Comment: It would be displayed in your answer's "source", after your uploaded the image. But the image might not show up the viewable version. Perhaps you could try uploading the relevant image into your question above?

Comment: I was tempted to edit this post to include a screenshot of the problem, but decided against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically use this trick to embed images in my posts and make them so you can click on them to get their original sizes.

```
[![image test][1]][1]
```

For example:

[image: image test]

This trick embeds an image reference, `![image test][1]` inside of another linked reference, `[..above..][1]`. Doing it this way allows for the image to be clicked on so that the original can be seen when needed.

Comment: Umm, that's been happening automatically for a few months now.

Comment: @Scott - yeah, I still do it this way so that I can control it + the alignment more explicitly.